# jqgrid not Loading on Start. How do I make it load data when grid loads?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am using jqgrid plugin for the first time. everything is good except for the data not loading on when the grid starts here:http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/16/capturadepantalla201305r.png "grid" . The data is grabbed from the DB but only as soon as I click  on any of the headers/sorters it loads all my data. How can I fix so it loads from the start? I am a total noob and would appreciate any help yall.
here is my code:

My PHP load:

```
// Get the requested page. By default grid sets this to 1. 
$page = $_GET['page']; 

// get how many rows we want to have into the grid - rowNum parameter in the grid 
$limit = $_GET['rows']; 

// get index row - i.e. user click to sort. At first time sortname parameter -
// after that the index from colModel 
$sidx = $_GET['sidx']; 

// sorting order - at first time sortorder 
$sord = $_GET['sord']; 

// if we not pass at first time index use the first column for the index or what you want
if(!$sidx) $sidx =1; 

// connect to the MySQL database server 
$db = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpassword) or die("Connection Error: " . mysql_error()); 

// select the database 
mysql_select_db($database) or die("Error connecting to db."); 

// calculate the number of rows for the query. We need this for paging the result 
$result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM demo"); 
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC); 
$count = $row['count']; 

// calculate the total pages for the query 
if( $count > 0 && $limit >5) { 
              $total_pages = ceil($count/$limit); 
} else { 
              $total_pages = 5; 
} 

// if for some reasons the requested page is greater than the total 
// set the requested page to total page 
if ($page > $total_pages) $page=$total_pages;

// calculate the starting position of the rows 
$start = $limit*$page - $limit;

// if for some reasons start position is negative set it to 0 
// typical case is that the user type 0 for the requested page 
if($start <0) $start = 0; 

// the actual query for the grid data 
$SQL = "SELECT id, name, id_continent, lastvisit,cdate, ddate,email FROM demo ORDER BY $sidx $sord LIMIT $start , $limit"; 
$result = mysql_query( $SQL ) or die("Couldn't execute query.".mysql_error()); 

// we should set the appropriate header information. Do not forget this.
header("Content-type: text/xml;charset=utf-8");

$s = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>";
$s .=  "<rows>";
$s .= "<page>".$page."</page>";
$s .= "<total>".$total_pages."</total>";
$s .= "<records>".$count."</records>";

// be sure to put text data in CDATA
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $s .= "<row id='". $row['id']."'>";  
        $s .= "<cell>". $row['id']."</cell>";
        $s .= "<cell><![CDATA[". $row['name']."]]></cell>";
    $s .= "<cell><![CDATA[". $row['id_continent']."]]></cell>";
    $s .= "<cell>". $row['lastvisit']."</cell>";
    $s .= "<cell>". $row['cdate']."</cell>";
    $s .= "<cell>". $row['ddate']."</cell>";
    $s .= "<cell><![CDATA[". $row['email']."]]></cell>";
    $s .= "</row>";
}
$s .= "</rows>"; 

echo $s;
?>
```

HTML:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/ui.jqgrid.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/nhf.css" />


<style type="text/css">
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 90%;
}
</style>

<script src="js/jquery-1.9.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){ 
  $("#list").jqGrid({
    url:'request.php',
    datatype: 'xml',
    mtype: 'GET',
    height: 'auto',
    colNames:['id','Project', 'Assigned To','Assign Date','Check Date','Due Date','Attachments'],
    colModel :[ 
      {name:'id', index:'id', width:20}, 
      {name:'name', index:'name', width:200, align:'left'}, 
      {name:'id_continent', index:'id_continent', width:80, align:'right'}, 
      {name:'lastvisit', index:'lastvisit', width:70, align:'right'}, 
      {name:'cdate', index:'cdate', width:70, align:'right'}, 
      {name:'ddate', index:'ddate', width:70, align:'right',datefmt:'(mm/d/YY)',date:'true'}, 
      {name:'email', index:'email', width:70,align:'center',sortable:false} 
    ],
    pager: '#pager',
    rowNum:10,
    rowList:[10,20,30],
    sortname: 'invid',
    sortorder: 'desc',
    viewrecords: true,
    gridview: true,
    caption: 'Pending Assignements'
  }); 
}); 
</script>

</head>
```

Comment: I got it. I had the sort name wrong. sortname: 'invid', when it should be "id". Thanks

Comment: Add this as the answer and Mark as the answer to close the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. I had the sort name wrong. sortname: 'invid', when it should be "id". Thanks